# Learning CWP, getting 502 bad gateway error

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, web-hosting, vps

So I have two different VPS which have the Control Web Panel OS installed. One of them is for my personal use, and one is for a client. The one I have for my personal use is working fine (I set it up in like January/February) but the one for my client is giving me never ending issues. On each VPS I'm running a NodeJS app through CWP's built in NodeJS manager. I attempted to copy the config step by step from my personal VPS to my client's, but I'm seeing 502 Bad Gateway on my client's. I have heard that 502 Bad Gateway can be specifically related to PHP-FPM service not running, but in CWP that service is behind a paywall. My personal VPS is not on a paid plan and does not have this same issue.

I have grabbed the files from my working personal project and uploaded them into my client's VPS to test if they work and they do not, same error. I tried uploading the files from my client's project into my personal (working) VPS and get a Proxy Error (as follows).

```
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

This would likely imply that the project I made for my client is flawed in some way? However when I host it locally it works just fine.

I'll include all the dependencies of my project, though I'm pretty new to all of this and not sure exactly what will be relevant.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
const sessions = require('express-session');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { fileLoader } = require("ejs");
```

Any guidance or direction on how to begin troubleshooting this (hopefully without upgrading to the pro plan of CWP) would be awesome.

Edit: I've continued troubleshooting and seem to have narrowed down that this issue lies with MongoDB Atlas, which I'm using on the backend. I installed Mongosh onto my VPS but couldn't connect to my Atlas instance. Eventually I opened up port 27017 in Firewalld and was suddenly able to connect to Atlas via CWP's simple terminal. I thought for sure that this would allow me to load the pages of my site which talk to MongoDB, however it still cannot. Pages which do not communicate with MongoDB load fine, but pages which do use MongoDB give 502 Proxy Error. Also, I have allow-listed the correct ip on MongoDB Atlas.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up switching to OpenLiteSpeed with Node.js and after a couple days of fighting it and a long conversation with ChatGPT my site is up B).